# What is sptier0.js

Tags: javascript, sitecore, http-status-code-404

We have a Sitecore installation, and in our environment we are seeing 404 errors when our site is requesting the following files:

- sptier0.js
- sptier0-ajax.js
- sptier0-window.js

My Google-fu doesn't turn up much.

What are these files, and what in their purpose?

Thanks!

Comment: What part of Sitecore generates those errors? Front-end or back office? I quickly checked my Sitecore instances and hound no such files. Is that any custom code of yours?

Comment: Sounds like these are custom scripts, they are not default Sitecore ones. Check for references to these files in your own code base.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that these scripts are most probably related to SharePath performance  monitoring tool of Correlsense (http://www.correlsense.com/product/).

I would start the investigation from viewing the html source in a browser, finding the place where the scripts are injected and then analyzing the sources in this area to find how does these links appear on the page.

Comment: In any case, that is not Sitecore functionality and there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: There's always a need to worry if it's throwing 404s, Sitecore or not.

Comment: Correlsense... bad! We found issues where Correlsense was modifying DLLs at runtime and which lead to Glass mapper failing to cast correctly.  As a result, we promptly uninstalled Correlsense and solved that problem.  I haven't yet confirmed if our sptier files have disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

These JavaScript files are indeed part of SharePath.
Specifically, they are added to existing application HTML pages in order to measure and report browser timing.

Your question, in addition to your comment to Vadim Dubovitsky, suggest that the tool was not properly uninstalled - the files were deleted, but they are still being referenced by (or injected into) the application code.

Disclaimer: I work at Correlsense.